# Show different elements of a form depending on dropdown box selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have a page that has a dropdown list and form.  And what I want to do is depending on the option selected in the dropdown list I want to hide and show different parts of the form.

```
<select id="myselect>
    <option id="option1">Option_1</option>
    <option id="option2">Option_2</option>
    <option id="option3">Option_3</option>
</select>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text" />
    <input id="input_2" name="input_2" type="text" />
    <input id="input_3" name="input_3" type="text" />
</form>
```

So if Option_1 is selected then show input_1 and input_3, while hiding input_2

Comment: Make sure you have a trailing " on id="myselect" too

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("myselect").onchange=function() {
    document.getElementById("input_2").style.display=(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=="option1")?"none":"block";
  }
  document.getElementById("myselect").onchange(); //trigger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get your issue resolved by adding a 'value' attribute to your option tags:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option id="option1" value="option1">Option_1</option>
    <option id="option2" value="option2">Option_2</option>
    <option id="option3" value="option3">Option_3</option>
</select>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text" placeholder="input_1"/>
    <input id="input_2" name="input_2" type="text" placeholder="input_2"/>
    <input id="input_3" name="input_3" type="text" placeholder="input_3"/>
</form>​
```

and using the jquery .change() event:

```
$select = $('#myselect');
$('#input_2').hide();
$('#input_3').hide(); 


$select.change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "option1"){
        if($('#input_1').is(":hidden")){
            $('#input_1').show();            
        }        
        $('#input_2').hide();
        $('#input_3').hide(); 
    }
    if($(this).val() == "option2"){
        if($('#input_2').is(":hidden")){
            $('#input_2').show();            
        }
        $('#input_1').hide();
        $('#input_3').hide(); 
    }
    if($(this).val() == "option3"){
        if($('#input_3').is(":hidden")){
            $('#input_3').show();            
        }
        $('#input_1').hide();
        $('#input_2').hide(); 
    }     
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukNKP/14/)

Comment: may not be what you were wanting, as i just reread your question. when you select option_1, you want to show both input_1 and input_3? In that case I failed.