# set function onchange in dropdown - PHP

Tags: php

I have a dropdown list and when when user selects a value and a different forms will appear depends on what the selected value. My file is in html. I'm using bootstrap for my design.

here is my sample code:

```
<form name="exmType" method = "POST">
<select class="form-control" name="txtType" class="select" method = "post"
onChange="this.form.submit();" style="width:300px;">
    <option value="">Option A</option>
    <option value="1">Option B</option>
    <option value="2">Option C </option>    
<?php

if (isset($_POST['txtType'])) {
if ( $_POST['txtType'] == "" ){
       *display form a*
} elseif ( $_POST['txtType'] == 1 ){
        *display form b*
 } elseif ( $_POST['txtType'] == 2 ){
        *display form c*
 }
}

?>

  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: **this.form.submit** what form?

Comment: Why do you use jQuery to hook an event that shows the form according to the value of the select element? it's much simpler.

Comment: @odedta I'm not really familiar with jQuery, I haven't code in a while and I'm still lost at the moment.

Comment: I'll write a simple example for you to fiddle with.

Comment: That would be really helpful! Thank you @odedta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple code example for what you need, you can fiddle with it for your needs.

The code is really simple so I don't see any reason to elaborate on what it does, if you have any questions post a comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '0') {
           $('form').css('display','none');
        }
        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
           $('form').css('display','none');
           $('#form_a').css('display','block');
        }
        if($(this).val() == '2') {
           $('form').css('display','none');
           $('#form_b').css('display','block');
        }
        if($(this).val() == '3') {
           $('form').css('display','none');
           $('#form_c').css('display','block');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
form {
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="0">-- Choose Form --</option>
    <option value="1">Form A</option>
    <option value="2">Form B</option>
    <option value="3">Form C</option>
</select>
<form id="form_a" method="post" role="form">
    Form a: <input type="text" value="form_a_text"/>
</form>
<form id="form_b" method="post" role="form">
    Form b: <input type="text" value="form_b_text"/>
</form>
<form id="form_c" method="post" role="form">
    Form c: <input type="text" value="form_c_text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This is a great example. Though I am still working on my codes. Thank you for your help

Comment: Cheers! if you have any questions just post a comment :)

Comment: I have to admit, at first I didn't know what I should do the example you gave me, took me a few times to re-read your code to finally understand it. I'm code works just fine now. :D

Comment: Really? I was sure it was self-explanatory. Oh well, good to know you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Jquery:

```
<script>
$('form select[name=txtType]').change(function(){
  if ($('form select option:selected').val() == '1'){
    $('#optionA').show();
  }else{
    $('#optionA').hide();
  }
});

$('form select[name= txtType]').change(function(){
  if ($('form select option:selected').val() == '2'){
    $('#optionB').show();
  }else{
    $('#optionB ').hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

You can find the Jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/ecZrE/

Some good answers: 
[Show Form Field if Drop Down Item is Selected Using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088381/show-form-field-if-drop-down-item-is-selected-using-jquery)

[Javascript: Trying to show different forms based on drop down value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611082/javascript-trying-to-show-different-forms-based-on-drop-down-value)

[Drop down menu selection ditactes what form will display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547528/drop-down-menu-selection-ditactes-what-form-will-display)

[Show different elements of a form depending on dropdown box selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389346/show-different-elements-of-a-form-depending-on-dropdown-box-selection)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your select tag has two `class=`. Choose the right one.

```
   `<select class="form-control"       name="txtType" class="select" method =       "post"
   onChange="this.form.submit();"         style="width:300px;">
<option value="">Option A</option>
<option value="1">Option B</option>
<option value="2">Option C </option>`
```

To add the onClick or onChange event use below function. Before adding it would be better if you add an `id` to the select tag.

`$('#select_tag_id').change(function(){
     $('#form_id_to_display').show('slow');
     $('#form_id_to_hide').hide('slow');
});`

Add above code in head section or at the botton of the page.

Sorry for wrong alignments. posting from mobile phone. Editing option is limited.